# Android Beginner Dialog doesn't show

Tags: android, xml

Here is my function

```
private void openCustomMenu() {


    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.setTitle("Bus Stops");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom);      
    layout.removeAllViews();

    for (String name : StopNames){
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkbox.setText(name);
        checkbox.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        layout.addView(checkbox);
    }

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.show();
}
```

and here my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/custom">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to add checkboxes dynamically but the dialog doesn't show when the function is called. If you know what is the problem, please tell me :) Thank you very much !

edit: it shows up actually but there is just the title and no checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.show();
```

What happens there is, everything you do before that is replaced by the `R.layout.custom` which you have provided the xml for. Nothing inside it.

If you want to verify that, place a `TextView` inside that xml and check
Or
Just comment that second `setContentView` and run your code.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call dialog.show(). Also you should remove the second setContentView statement - it will overwrite everything you did in the loop.

Apart from that I don't really follow what you did - why inflate a view from XML and them remove everything from it? 
You should look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html, specifically setMultiChoiceItems - that's the proper way do achieve what you need.

Comment: Remove the second `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);` would probably be enough to solve his issue.

Comment: That's true however I'd strongly recommended dumping that approach completely and use some flavor of `setMultiChoiceItems` on a Builder - That method's purpose is to show a dialog with checkboxes which is exactly what is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish up your code with a dialog.show() which actually shows the dialog.